# Error detection in multiple queries in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a wrapper php class for mysqli which amongst other things needs to be able to handle multiple queries (using mysqli::multi_query). It works but I can't find how I'm supposed to get error details when one of the queries fails. This is a simplified version of the code:

```
$queries=array('SELECT * FROM core_order_items',
                'SELaaaaECT * FROM core_order_items',
                );

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'siella', 'arifisis', 'mydb');
$dbConnection->set_charset('utf8'); 
$dbConnection->multi_query(implode(';', $queries)) ;

$i=0;
do {
    echo "Query:  " . $queries[$i] . " - ";
    $resultset=$dbConnection->store_result();
    if($resultset===false && strlen($dbConnection->errno)>0) {
        echo "Returned error for query " . $i . "<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Returned set for query " . $i . "<br>";
    }
     $i++;
}   
while ($dbConnection->next_result());

mysqli_close($dbConnection);
```

Notice how of the two SQL queries the first is fine and the second invalid.
The result is:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM core_order_items - Returned set for query 0
```

What happened to my second query? If I fix it, it shows up, but when an error occurs it's as if it isn't even in the array. How do I get the error no/message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli::next_result returns false if there is an error. This example is from the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
$dbConnection-->multi_query($query); 
do { 
   $dbConnection-->use_result()->close(); 
   echo "Okay\n"; 
} while ($mysqli->next_result()); 

if ($mysqli->errno) { 
   echo "Stopped while retrieving result : ".$mysqli->error; 
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it was doing error checking before an error occurred. Then just as an error came up it would stop checking. Wonderful.

Comment: It does not work for me. 
At first - it is not clear what "mysqli_report" flags should I use?

Comment: Secondly, I use SQL code: "set @q=1;select @q as max_id from dual1;" and "$mysqli->errno" has no errors for me. When it should be something like this: "[Err] 1146 - Table 'test.dual1' doesn't exist".

Comment: Thirdly, "mysqli::next_result" return false when it has no next result, like when you reach the end of the list of your SQL queries - so there should be a way to determine either there was the end of the list or it was an error.